# Unexpected character (at character 2)

Tags: flutter, dart

Got an Error While Parsing data while handleing Error

Unexpected character (at character 2)
{error: {code: 400, message: Cannot read property 'password' of null, detai...
^

Another exception was thrown: FormatException: Unexpected character (at character 2)

MyResponse

```
   {
    "error": {
        "code": 400,
        "message": "Cannot read property 'password' of null",
        "details": ""
    }
}
```

This is how i try to parse response

LoginErrorResponse errorResponse = LoginErrorResponse.fromJson(jsonDecode(snapshot.data.error.errorBody));

errorBody:
{error: {code: 400, message: Cannot read property 'password' of null, details: }}

ModelClass

```
class LoginErrorResponse {
    LoginError error;

    LoginErrorResponse({this.error});

    LoginErrorResponse.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
        error = json['error'] != null ? new LoginError.fromJson(json['error']) : null;
    }

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
        final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
        if (this.error != null) {
            data['error'] = this.error.toJson();
        }
        return data;
    }
}

class LoginError {
    int code;
    String message;
    String details;

    LoginError({this.code, this.message, this.details});

    LoginError.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
        code = json['code'];
        message = json['message'];
        details = json['details'];
    }

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
        final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
        data['code'] = this.code;
        data['message'] = this.message;
        data['details'] = this.details;
        return data;
    }
}
```

Response handeling

```
Future<ApiResponse<ResultType>> _getResponse() async {

      try {
        Response response = await createApiAsync();
        print(response.data.toString());
        if (response.statusCode >= 200 && response.statusCode <= 299) {
          ResultType responseModel = parseJson(response);
          onSuccess(responseModel);
          return ApiResponse.success<ResultType>(responseModel);
        } else{
          return ApiResponse.failed<ResultType>(Error(response.statusCode,
              response.data.toString(), response.statusMessage.toString()));

        }
      } on DioError catch (e, stacktrace) {
        if(e.response!=null) {
          return ApiResponse.failed<ResultType>(Error(e.response.statusCode,
              e.response.statusMessage, e.response.data.toString()));

        } else{
          // Something happened in setting up or sending the request that triggered an Error
          print(e.request);
          print(e.message);
        }        // return ApiResponse.failed<ResultType>(
        //     Error(response.statusCode, response.statusMessage,response.data));
      }

  }
```

My StreamBuilder

```
 StreamBuilder<ApiResponse<LoginResponse>>(
          stream: bloc.subject.stream,
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (!snapshot.hasData) {
              print("bkbbjbkjhjkj:${snapshot.data.error.statusCode}");
    
              return Text("${snapshot.data.error.errorBody}");
            } else {
    
              switch (snapshot.data.status) {
                case Status.LOADING:
                return CircularProgressIndicator();
                  break;
                case Status.SUCCESS:
              return  Text("${snapshot.data.data}");
                  break;
                case Status.ERROR:
                  print("myerrorhandling:${snapshot.data.error.errorBody}");
                  if(snapshot.data.error.errorBody.isNotEmpty){
                  LoginErrorResponse errorResponse = LoginErrorResponse.fromJson(json.decode(snapshot.data.error.errorBody));
                  print("asdatthyhtgdschyt${errorResponse.error.message}");
                  }
                 return Text("${snapshot.data.error}");
                  break;
                default:
                  return Container();
    //    }
              }
              return Container();
            }
          })
```

Comment: ```LoginErrorResponse.fromJson(jsonDecode(snapshot.data.error.errorBody));```, can you print the value of `snapshot.data.error.errorBody` to see if it is the actual `map intended to be parsed?`

Comment: yeah i can print the value.. its like {error: {code: 400, message: Cannot read property 'password' of null, details: }}  @void

Comment: Can you post the code snippet where you are getting `data` from the `snapshot` ?

Comment: yeah i have update it in my question . Its like {error: {code: 400, message: Cannot read property 'password' of null, details: }}

Comment: I mean show the code snippet where you are using the `FutureBuilder` || `StreamBuilder` widget( I guess).

Comment: updatd my question with streambuilder

Answer (score 1):

After Couple of hour i found a solution.The Trick is just encoding the errorresponse

```
if(e.response!=null) {
return ApiResponse.failed<ResultType>(Error(e.response.statusCode,
e.response.statusMessage, jsonEncode(e.response.data)));

}
```